# парсинг по вложенным спискам

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

4-й день воюю с задачей, вопрос следующий:
Есть пара DF (очевидно что фреймы тестовые - реальные немного отличаются но суть та же):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Отдел': ['отд_1', 'отд_1', 'отд_1', 'отд_2', 'отд_2', 'отд_2', 'отд_2'],'ФИО': ['Иванов Иван Иванович', 'Петров С.А.', 'Алексеев Евгений', 'Сидоров Георгий Иванович', 'Любимов Валерий Петрович', 'Сомов Рыб Рыбович','Иванов Иван Иванович',]})
df_lib = pd.DataFrame({'Отдел': ['отд_2', 'отд_2', 'отд_1'],'old': ['Иванов', 'Петров', 'Сидоров'],'new': ['Ivanov', 'Petrov', 'Sidorov']})
```

С помощью следующего кода я вытаскиваю группы слов для анализа (из `df_lib`) :

```
df['test'] = df["ФИО"].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(list(df_lib["old"])) + ')').merge(df_lib, left_on=0, right_on='old', how ='left')['new']
```

И как раз в этом коде есть вопрос! Дело в том что код проходит поиском слов по столбцу `df_lib["old"]` целиком что не верно, так как в примере есть одинаковые ФИО из разных отделов в разных отделах есть собственные пулы слов для парсинга! Есть ли идей как парсить слова по отделу а не целиком?
История с `if - else` или разбить группы на отдельные столбцы не подойдут так как групп (в нашем случае отделов) >1000

Пробывал играться с групповым `.merge`:

```
final_df = pd.merge(df, df_lib[['Отдел', 'new', 'old']], how="left", left_on=['Отдел', 'test'], right_on=['Отдел', 'new'])
```

- но так как на входе мы получаем столбец `test` -который как раз и отвечает за поиск слов, идея была отложена! Буду рад любым идеям! Спасибо!

Comment: вы много чего написали кроме основной задачи своего кода. что конкретно требуется сделать? может,  вам проще будет обойтись методом `groupby`, кто знает?

Comment: @strawdog Да вы правы про много всего, всю голову сломал с данным вопросом и есть стойкое ощущение что решение очень простое! По сути вопрос сводится к этой части кода `df['test'] = df["ФИО"].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(list(df_lib["old"])) + ')')` в котором нужно применить условие сопоставления групп. Сейчас добавлю вариант как должно получится! с `groupby `пока не знаком!

Comment: @strawdog пока описывал что конкретно нужно, сам дошёл до решения! Решение оказалось очень простым как я и догадывался! Я привёл данные к общему ключу (объединил необходимые столбцы) и просто merge-анул их! Вы очень помогли! Спасибо!